# Related sample t-test with missing values

Tags: repeated-measures, t-test, python

I want to run a t-test on two conditions tested repeatedly on the same population. I'm doing this via a python implementation of a related sample t-test (`scipy.stats.mstats.ttest_rel`).

The related sample t test requires my input arrays to have the same length. I do however have a number of missed measurements (which have a measurement value of "false", which python reads as zero and which distorts my t-test).

What would be the less disruptive way to deal with missed measurements:

- replace each missed measurement with the **mean** of the rest of the data
- replace each missed measurement with the **median** of the rest of the data
- delete for each missed measurement the valid measurement from the other condition

?

Comment: The options you offer are not the only options. For example, there are [overlapping samples tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Overlapping_samples).

Comment: wiki (and google in general) offer little clarification on this. Could you tell me what the difference between an overlapping sample test and a repeated sample test is? the scipy mailing list doesn't seem to know what it is either and a member said it probably makes many unhealthy assumptions: "If it mixes independent and paired t-tests, then it might require additional assumptions that might not be appropriate for a repeated measures setting."

Comment: google worked just fine for me, yielding a number of relevant hits. e.g. see the list at the bottom of page 8 of [this document](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mb55/overlap.pdf) (which lists several options that can be used with incomplete pairs), and the references at the end (in particular Shih, (1985).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on 1) How much data is missing and 2) Why there is missing data.

If there is very little missing then your 3 methods will give approximately equal results; the median is probably better than the mean, since it isn't affected by outliers, but deletion won't do too much damage unless the data are very not missing at random (see below).

If there is more than a little missing, then you have to consider the reasons for missingness. There are 3 sorts:

```
Missing completely at random (MCAR)
Missing at random (MAR)
Not missing at random (NMAR)
```

You can Google these terms or search for them here. However, in any of the three cases, the right answer is "none of the above" - that is, your 3 methods are all flawed. If the data are NMAR then there is no ideal solution. In the other two cases, multiple imputation is widely used and recommended. It may also be the best choice for NMAR data, but its results can't be guaranteed to be "right".

Comment: and what's "cleaner" - taking the median of the entire rest of the data, of the entire rest of the data for that participant, or of the entire rest of the data for that participant for that condition?

Comment: Well, I advise against any of those. But if you insist an single imputation, you can look into various methods. [This page](http://missingdata.lshtm.ac.uk/) seems to have some good stuff. And [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/missing.pdf) is some material by Andrew Gelman who is expert.

Comment: well, you said it was ok if only a few values were missing. I'd say roughly 0.5% of my values are missing.

Comment: Also, the data seems to be missing completely at random. I believe it's a quirk of the experiment presentation software (psychopy) - every few hundred trials or so I get a null or negative reaction time.

Comment: Oh, OK. Then either deletion is probably easiest and it almost surely won't matter much